# is there a way of hiding a modal in ajax after return a response

Tags: javascript

When an ajax request has been sent and the response is still in progress, I want to put the page in loading mode by showing a static modal.

When I call the function that shows the modal, it works fine.

But I cannot hide the modal or stop the loading mode.

How can I fix this?

Also I apologize if my words are not clear! I hope you get it

The function that handles the hide and show of my modal:
[image]

```js
 $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/manage_quizzez/" + actionType,
      headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken },
      beforeSend: function (data) {
        $("#add_category").modal("hide");
        toggleLoadModal("show");
      },
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      data: formData,
      async: false,
      success: function (response) {
        toggleLoadModal("hide");
        if (!response.isError) {
          Swal.fire({
            title: "Successfully",
            text: response.Message,
            icon: "success",
            confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-primary w-xs mt-2",
            buttonsStyling: !1,
            showCloseButton: !0,
          }).then((e) => {
            e.value && RefreshPage();
          });
        } else {
          $("#add_category").modal("show");
          if (response.input == null) {
            Swal.fire({
              title: response.title,
              text: response.message,
              icon: response.icon,
              confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-primary w-xs mt-2",
              buttonsStyling: !1,
              showCloseButton: !0,
            });
          } else {
            $("#" + response.input)
              .parent()
              .find(".invalid-feedback")
              .css("display", "block");
            $("#" + response.input)
              .parent()
              .find(".invalid-feedback")
              .text(data.message);
          }
        }
      },
      error: function (response) {},
      complete: function (data) {
        toggleLoadModal("hide");
      },
    });
```

Comment: Both your success and complete handlers call the `toggleLoadModal()` function. On a successful response, both of those will fire, so your modal will effectively stay the same. Also, why are you checking the response for errors in the success callback?

Comment: It worked for me so well after couple of tries , and if i given you the answer of why i am checking error in success , it's that a way i do things and it tells me that the action went well or not , in order to give the user a suitable answer of what he is doing, thnakz

Comment: The success handler only fires when the request was successfully carried out. No need to check for errors there. "The way I do things" doesn't make it correct.

Comment: Yes! i agree with you that , i know how success works , it tells that the server completed your request successfully , i means with this phrase "The way I do things" i have my own logic getting responses from the server when successfully returned , it just logical coding, and there is nothing wrong

Comment: Regardless, what I said before is still true. You are calling the same function in both the success and complete callback, which both fire when the call is successful and therefore you're toggling the modal twice.